# How to fix Update and Set command in in OLEDB, SQL?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

Using OLEDB and SQl to interact with an access database, and I need to update one column of the database however there is an error

This is made in vb.net.
I have made sure they are being set in the correct order based off of my database

```
Dim sql As String = "UPDATE UserInfo SET Password=?, CurrentLevel=?  WHERE Username=?" & LoggedInUsername 'TheSQL/DDL code to update
Dim comd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, Connstring) ' create a COMMAND for this SQL
'set up all the parameters needed but they must be set in the same order as used in SQL
MsgBox(Dlevel & " 1 Is Working")

' comd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", LoggedInUsername)
comd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", LoggedInPassword)
comd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentLevel", Dlevel)

MsgBox(Dlevel & " 2 Is Working")

comd.ExecuteNonQuery()    'Execute the command
```

It should update the database to change the Current Level. I have used message boxes to find where the problem is and it is when the command is being executed

Comment: Please include the error message

Comment: `"UPDATE UserInfo SET [Password]=@Password, CurrentLevel=@CurrentLevel (...)"`. The **parameters** need to follow the order of the fields. Try using `[Command].Parameters.Add()` instead of `[Command].Parameters.AddWithValue()`. Many SO questions/answers explain why. For example. `comd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = LoggedInUsername`